# Can't create element with "primary" or "onPrimary" classes in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm making an app in Flutter, but I have a problem that I can't solve and I can't find anything about it on the internet. My problem is that on my IDE the "primary" and "onPrimary" classes of material 3 do not work since I installed the latest version of the flutter sdk.

Code Example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Button'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('Button Pressed');
            },
            child: Text('Mon bouton'),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.blue,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On VSCode, my error is :

> The named parameter 'primary' isn't defined.
> Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'primary'.dartundefined_named_parameter

I tried to reinstall an old one but that did nothing changed, I did some test code and to see if the problem didn't just come from the project but no, so I'm stuck.

And I saw that there was an element like:

```
backgroundColor: colorScheme.secondary,
foregroundColor: colorScheme.onSecondary,
```

Except that I would like to solve my problem and keep the "primary" and "onPrimary" classes

Comment: I see you setting the colors, but where are you trying to use them?

Comment: I just use them for the colors of my buttons

Comment: `primary` and `onPrimary` are properties from the [ColorScheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html) class

Answer (score 0):

If you look at VSCode's auto suggestions, it offers to change `primary` to `foregroundColor`.

The error says `primary isn't defined` because that field doesn't exist in new flutter version.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I did in the end even though I would have preferred to keep primary